# Integrate[(1 + x/n)^n*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I evaluated

```
Integrate[(1 + x/n)^n*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}] .
```

thinking the answer should be approximately $\sqrt{\pi n/2}$. *Mathematica* gave me

> ConditionalExpression[E^n n ExpIntegralE[-n, n], Re[n] > 0 || n ∉ Reals]

which I am not sure how to interpret.  How can I get *Mathematica* to give me something closer to what I was expecting?

Comment: Try `Integrate[(1 + x/n)^n*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity} , 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]`, i.e. use the assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n > 0,
 FunctionExpand@Integrate[(1 + x/n)^n Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]

(* E^n n^-n Gamma[1 + n, n] *）
```

Comment: Thanks very much. To get what I was hoping for I would need Mathematica to be able to give detailed asymptotics for Gamma[1 + n, n]  which is too much for it I think

Comment: Note that this result is not very different from what the OP got, since the [incomplete gamma function and the exponential integral are closely related](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19.E1).